# Drückt »aber wie!« das Gleiche wie »und wie!« aus?

Tags: interjection

Aus [einem Interview](http://taz.de/Politikwissenschaftler-ueber-Smartphones/!157580/):

> – Es wird diskutiert, warum die Schule das Handyverbot in den Pausen aufhebt.
>   – Sie sind dagegen?
>   – **Aber wie!** Damit wäre das kindliche Spiel auf dem Schulhof beendet.

Drückt »aber wie!« das Gleiche wie »und wie!« aus? Oder eben das Gegenteil?

Comment: "Und wie!" Ist das Normale. "Aber wie!"  wirst du wohl nicht so oft hören.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dem Beispiel in der Frage sind beide genau dasselbe: ein Mittel zur Intensivierung eines Statements.
Der einzige Unterschied ist meiner Meinung nach, dass „aber wie“ eher als ja-ähnliche Antwort auf eine Frage verwendet wird, während „und wie“ auch in einer Aussage funktioniert.

> „Ich habe Hunger.“
>   „Ich auch, und wie, ey.“

Hier passt „aber wie“ für mein Empfinden nicht so gut, aber das kann auch eingebildet sein.

Comment: Nach meinem Empfinden passt *aber wie* auch nicht als Antwort auf die Frage oben, aber vielleicht bin das nur ich.

Comment: @Jan, nein, mir geht es genauso. _Aber wie_ hört sich komisch an.

Comment: Ich würde sagen "eingebildet".

Answer (score 4):

*Und wie* ist (umgangssprachlicher) Standard, *aber wie* ist eher ungewöhnlich und bedeutet im Wesentlichen dasselbe. Soweit es einen Unterschied gibt, dürfte das der folgende sein:

*Und wie* schließt an das vorher Gesagte an. Es setzt voraus, dass etwas vom bisherigen Sprecher schon als groß / intensiv / beeindruckend / ... dargestellt oder angedeutet wurde und intensiviert das weiter.

*Aber wie* drückt aus, dass etwas noch viel größer / intensiver / beeindruckender / ... ist, als man aus dem bisherigen Kontext erwarten würde. Es ist also noch intensiver.

Da es in der Sprache bei derartigen Ausdrücken die Tendenz gibt, dass alte Wendungen sich abnutzen und durch neue, noch eindringlichere ersetzt werden, stehen die Chancen gut, dass *und wie* auf lange Sicht durch *aber wie* abgelöst werden wird. (Dagegen dürfte vor allem sprechen, dass *aber wie* eine Silbe mehr hat als *und wie*.) Selbst wenn das so ist, stehen wir aber erst ganz am Anfang der Entwicklung. *Aber wie* beginnt erst noch, sich auszubreiten. Momentan scheint es gerade erst die Kategorie derjenigen Wendungen zu verlassen, die von den meisten Muttersprachlern - selbst denen, die sie gelegentlich verwenden - für falsch erklärt werden, sobald sie bewusst darüber nachdenken.

Comment: Die Unterstellung, es gäbe eine Tendenz zu kürzeren Formulierungen, gemessen an Silben, ist m.E. nichts weiter als eine ad-hoc Vermutung von Hobbyisten, die sich nicht die geringste Mühe machen ihre These zu widerlegen, was ausgesprochen einfach ist. Man beachte nur das Aufkommen des Begriffs "zeitnah", der "nun", "jetzt", "bald", "schnell" usw. ersetzt.

Comment: Die Tendenz zu kürzeren Formulierungen ist natürlich nicht der einzige Faktor im Sprachwandel, und wenn er anderen entgegensteht ist er nicht unbedingt der ausschlaggebende. Der Vorteil von *zeitnah* ist, dass es so vage ist. Wenn man etwas sofort oder schnell erledigt, sagt man das auch heute noch so. *Zeitnah* bedeutet letztlich nur, dass es nicht so lange herausgezögert wird, bis es Ärger gibt.

Comment: Aber generell hältst Du an der Behauptung fest, dass es eine Tendenz gibt die Sprache zu verkürzen? Hast Du dafür Belege?

Comment: Alle Sprachen sind voll davon. Die Kasusendungen im Deutschen sind die Reste von vor-indogermanischen Postpositionen (sowas wie Präpositionen, nur hinter dem Substantiv - z.B. *wegen* in "der Kürze wegen"), die allmählich immer weiter verkürzt und mit den Substantiven verschmolzen wurden. Allerdings wurden sie in den letzten Jahren so weit verkürzt, dass sie z.T. kaum noch unterscheidbar sind, wodurch der Dativ und Genitiv auf dem Rückzug sind. Französisch und Englisch sind schon weiter: Die Kasusendungen sind da ganz weg. Ihre Funktion wird von *de/à* bzw. *of/to* übernommen.

Comment: Verkürzt wird tendenziell vor allem (1) häufig Gesagtes und (2) Unbetontes. Wobei (2) meinen Hinweis (der ja lediglich ein Gegenargument gegen meine Prognose vorwegnehmen sollte) natürlich stark relativiert: Für Dinge, die man betonen oder übertreiben will (wie hier der Fall), ist nämlich eher die umgekehrte Tendenz zu beobachten, dass Ausdrücke umständlich und lang gemacht werden.

Comment: Sprachliche Verkürzung wird in der linguistischen Literatur durchaus immer wieder als eines der wichtigen Phänomene des Sprachwandels beschrieben. Vor allem auch als ein kennzeichnendes Merkmal der deutschen Jugendsprache, die ja besonders wichtig für die Zukunft der Sprache ist. (Nach neueren Erkenntnissen vor allem die Sprache der jungen Mädchen.)

Comment: Hoppla! In der Bemerkung über Postposition -> Kasus -> Präposition sollte es natürlich "in den letzten Jahrhunderten" heißen, nicht "in den letzten Jahren". Leider kann ich das jetzt nicht mehr korrigieren.

Comment: Die Argumentation verfängt nicht, denn den Sprachwandel, den Du zum Zeugen anrufst, betrifft Endungen, nicht alternative Formulierungen, um die es hier geht. Ich sehe aber, dass die strittige Formulierung entfernt ist. Allerdings habe ich noch eine zweite Kritik. Du schreibst, die meisten Muttersprachler (letzter Absatz) würden die Formulierung für falsch erklärt haben, wenn sie darüber nachgedacht hätten. Woher nimmst Du dieses Wissen? Kann es sein, dass Du Dir das einfach ausgedacht hast, dass es reine Spekulation ist?

Comment: (1) Nichts ist entfernt. Mein einziger Edit war, diese Bemerkung hinzuzufügen. (2) Mein Beispiel ist heute Morphologie, war aber früher Syntax. Was ich über die Beschreibung von Verkürzung in der Literatur geschrieben habe gilt aber auch und gerade für die Syntax. Wie wärs mal mit eigener Literaturrecherche? (3) Meine Antwort beruhte tatsächlich auf Hintergrundwissen und dadurch geleiteter Introspektion. Die ist bei mir erfahrungsgemäß recht zuverlässig und bringt mich immerhin nicht auf so einen Stuss wie, Verkürzungstendenzen in der Syntax abzustreiten. (4) Ich werde ab jetzt DFTT befolgen.

Comment: ad1: Stimmt, ich habe die Markierung im Edit falsch interpretiert. Pardon. ad2: Sicher hast Du eine Quelle dafür. Kannst Du diese bitte benennen? ad3: Dein HIntergrundwissen und die Zuverlässigkeit Deiner Introspektion ist nur behauptet. Es ist allgemein bekannt dass wir zu Fehleinschätzungen neigen (bspw.: Confirmationbias) so dass ich mir erlaube diese Behauptung zu bestreiten. Immerhin habe ich ein Beispiel gebracht, bei dem Formulierungen im Laufe der Zeit länger werden - Du bringst weder Belege noch Beispiele. Die Frage, wer hier der Troll ist, kann man auch anders beantworten.